# In a GC environment, when will Core Data release its allocated memory?

Tags: cocoa, macos, core-data, memory-management

In my application, right now it seems that Core Data is busy allocating space in memory for different objects, however, it's never releasing that memory. The memory used by the application keeps growing the more it runs.

Is there a call to the Core Data context (or something else) that ensures all memory is cleaned up? When will Core Data release the allocated memory?

Thanks!

Comment: “Is there a call to the Core Data context (or something else) that ensures all memory is cleaned up?” Of course not. In GC-land, objects stay alive as long as something knows about them. If you somehow forced an object to get freed while something knows about it, you'd cause a crash later on—exactly what happens without GC when you release an object while something knows about it. There may be an answer to the other question, but I don't know enough about Core Data to know what it is, so I'll leave that for someone else to answer.

Comment: Thanks Peter. That's what seems weird to me. Since the Core Data context object seems to be used throughout the lifetime of an application, does that mean that anything related to the context object (i.e. everything declared in memory) will not be released until the application finishes/quits?

Comment: Everything still being held onto will not be released. Hopefully Core Data is smart enough to not hold onto everything forever. @JeremyP's link looks promising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even when core data has finished with an object (which might not be when you think), the garbage collector won't necessarily collect it straight away.

The garbage collector has two methods to trigger collection:  [collectIfNeeded](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSGarbageCollector_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004590-CH1-SW4) and [collectExhaustively](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSGarbageCollector_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004590-CH1-SW5).  The former doesn't guarantee to collect right now and the latter will probably stop your application for a bit.

You can force core data to fault its objects.  See [Reducing Memory Overhead](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003468-SW4) for details.